# rotate text in customview

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, rotatetransform

I'm able to draw a `NSString` in a `CustomView` using the `drawAtPoint` method:

```
NSString *text = @"text";
NSSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:xlabelSet]; //receive the text size
NSPoint p = NSMakePoint(length - textSize.width/2 , wcszero_y - 20); //define text position considering the text center
[text drawAtPoint:p withAttributes:xlabelSet]; //draw text at position
```

How do I rotate the text by 90 degree at the same position? What I found so far wasn't really rotating the text at the defined position.

Comment: Hello Dream Eater, Thanks for the answer. I looked it up and I'm not convinced since the Mac Developer Library states this: `If you want only to rotate an object to be drawn, it is not necessary to construct an affine transform to do so. The most direct way to rotate your drawing is by calling the function CGContextRotateCTM. `. So, Aleph7 is on the right track but I need to find out to adapt this to osx somehow.

Comment: your help doesn't help at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply a rotation to the graphics context:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI/2);

// ...
[text drawAtPoint:p withAttributes:xlabelSet]; //draw text at position
```

Comment: Hello Aleph7, thank you for the answer. It looks like its for iOS. Is there something similar for osx as well?

Comment: using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` gives an error `implicit declaration of function 'UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext' is invalid in C99`. What the heck does that mean?

Comment: replace the first line with `CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];`

Comment: Hello Aleph7, thanks for keeping up here. The changes do actually rotate the text but I think I still need to do some more research. It seems to be not as easy as I thought in the first place. Thanks anyhow.